# How to put a dot on a boldsymbol letter in LaTeX?

Tags: boldsymbol

I am trying to put a dot on a boldsymbol letter,

```
\dot{\boldsymbol{\tilde{x}}}(t)
```

but I get this,

[image]

but I want to have,

[image]

with a \tilde between dot and x.

Comment: And what would you like to have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better using `bm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$\dot{\bm{\tilde{x}}}(t)$

\end{document}
```

You can also use `\boldsymbol`, there's no need to change all your source files except for adding `\usepackage{bm}`.

[image]

Comment: Great! That's I really want :)

Comment: And how about this one, \mathbf{\dot{\tilde{P}}}? It seems using \bm instead on \mathbf gives different result.

Comment: @egreg: for the bold and italic format of the letter, as you see in your solution, the dot should be aligned a little bit to the right. I have also this problem for \bm and \symboldbold cases. Please let me know how we can sole this. This is obvious for $\dot{\bm{X}}$.

Answer (score 2):

`\boldsymbol{\dot{\tilde{x}}}(t)`

does the trick I think

Comment: That works but I don't want the dot to be bold :(